# Find all intersection in N polygons

Tags: geospatial, computational-geometry

Given **N** polygons which are represented by points of the boundary, find all group of intersected polygons.

For example, input `[polygon_A, polygon_B, polygon_C, polygon_D]` as below, output `[(polygon_A, polygon_B), (polygon_B, polygon_C)]` (Note that polygon_A is a struct that contains `uniq_ID` and `list[points]`.)

Is it possible that I can process faster than O(n^2) (Assumed that each polygon contains no more than 10 points)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the outlines as sets of independent line segments and find all intersections using (for instance) a sweepline technique. The complexity reaches `O((n+k) log n)` where `k` is the effective number of intersections.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_Bentley-Ottmann

In your case, if the polygons are compact and scattered, you can also consider their axis-aligned bounding boxes and find the overlaps. An `O(n log n + k)` algorithm is known.